# Происхождение слова зависть

Tags: этимология

Неужели в действительности зависть происходит от "вид", "видеть"? Интересно, каким образом слово "видно" с помощью приставки "за" приобрело такой смысл?

Answer (score 1):

Получается, что так. Изначально было что-то вроде "смотреть издали", и оно имело одним из значений "смотреть недоброжелательно" (похожие коннотации можно заметить и в современном языке). Ниже точнее и подробнее из этимологического словаря Шапошникова.

> **Зависть** – чувство досады, вызванное благополучием, успехом другого. ▲ В рус. языке XI–XVII вв. изв. *завида, зависть, завистьныи,
>   завистивыи*. ▲ Из праслав. *зависть (*завидть, где -т —
>   основообразующий суф.), производного от основы глаг. *завидěти «видеть
>   издали», «начать видеть», «засмотреться», «смотреть
>   недоброжелательно». Примечательная параллель – лат. invidia.

Answer (score 1):

[**Зависть**](http://slovo.dn.ua/zavist.html)

> Древнее слово *зависть* вошло в лексикон многих славянских языков. Оно
>   образовано от существительного *завида* при помощи
>   суффикса *-ть*. От устаревшего для современного языка *завида* было
>   образовано и прилагательное *завидный:* являющийся предметом зависти;
>   прекрасный, такой, которого можно желать для себя.
>
> Этимологи показывают, что слова *зависть, завидовать, завистливый и
>   завидный* исторически родственные глаголу *видеть*.

---

Убедительного источника нет. Вот сайтик предлагает свои сокровища:

[Этимологические словари на нашем портале:](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B7/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

- словарь Крылова
- словарь Семёнова
- словарь Успенского
- словарь Фасмера
- словарь Шанского

(Как видите, [г-на Шапошникова](http://www.ruslang.ru/node/1139) в списке нет, а объясняется просто: не заслужил пока должного авторитета.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Смысловую связь с глаголом "видеть" осмотрительный Фасмер определяет так: основано, вероятно, на представлении о дурном глазе.

А категоричнее всех Шанский (ему не с руки кружева плести), и он замечательно чётко проговаривает, ***откуда взялась приставка "за": она искони была, у слова *завида* с приплюсованным суффиксом (вид/видеть отдалились, хотя и родня).***

[Ви́деть. Общеслав. индоевроп. характера. Суф. производное от той же основы, что и лат. vidēre «видеть»; готск. weitan «смотреть, наблюдать» и др. См. ведать.](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C)

Можно посмотреть и на "ведать", но глубже неэтимологу уже ходить не стоит.

[Ве́дать (знать). Итератив к общеслав. вести (е из «ять») «знать», возникшему из *vědti после изменения dt > tt > ст и «ять» > е (ср. брести, плести и т. п.).](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)